# Pygame: Game Over Screen not displaying when in theory, it should

Tags: python, time, pygame

I'm back at it with this game and it almost works, the gameplay is almost right but it's just the game over screen.
Basically, it's supposed to blit the game-over screen when the player's lives drop to 0 and then wait 5 seconds before closing.

In this MCVE example, I've made it so the player's lives decrement every 0.5 seconds but it still produces the same issue.

I've dry-run the program a few times and can't see what's wrong with it.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import time
import itertools
import os

pygame.init()
SCREENWIDTH = 1000
SCREENHEIGHT = 650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption("Eleeza Crafter: The Cloud Colours", "EleezaCrafter")
screen.fill((255, 123, 67))
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 188), (0, 50, 1000, 650), 0)
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Ink Free', 30)
gameoverscreen = myfont.render('Game Over!', False, (0, 0, 0))

background = screen.copy()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
stageon = True

def gameover():
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("gameover.png"), (0,0))
    time.sleep(5)
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    sprite = pygame.image.load("Sprites/lee.png")

    def __init__(self, *groups):
        super().__init__(*groups)
        self.image = Player.sprite
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(445, 550))
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(self.rect.topleft)
        self.lives = 10
        self.score = 0
        self.hitbox = self.rect.inflate(-3, -3)
    def update(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        dist = 2
        if key[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.y += dist
            self.hitbox.y += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_UP]:
            self.rect.y -= dist
            self.hitbox.y -= dist
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.x += dist
            self.hitbox.x += dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.x -= dist
            self.hitbox.x -= dist

        if self.rect.right > SCREENWIDTH:
            self.rect.right = SCREENWIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0
        if self.rect.bottom > SCREENHEIGHT:
            self.rect.bottom = SCREENHEIGHT
        if self.rect.top < 50:
            self.rect.top = 50

        self.lives -= 1
        time.sleep(0.5)

        if self.lives <= 0:
            screen.blit(pygame.image.load("gameover.png"), (0,0))
            time.sleep(5)
            os._exit(0)
            pygame.quit()
            stageon = False



sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player(sprites)

lives = myfont.render('Lives: {0}'.format(player.lives), False, (255, 255, 255))

def main():
    while stageon:
        for events in pygame.event.get():
            if events.type == pygame.QUIT or stageon == False:
                screen.blit(pygame.image.load("gameover.png"), (0,0))
                time.sleep(5)
                pygame.quit()
                return


        sprites.update()
        lives = myfont.render('Lives: {0}'.format(player.lives), False, (255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(lives, (850, 0))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(100)
        if stageon == False:
            screen.blit(pygame.image.load("gameover.png"), (0, 0))
            time.sleep(5)
            return
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If anyone knows what amateur mistake I've made *this* time, that'd be great.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `update` function, modify the block:

```
if self.lives <= 0:
    screen.blit(pygame.image.load("gameover.png"), (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip() # Add this.
    time.sleep(5)
    os._exit(0)
    pygame.quit()
    stageon = False
```

Should update the screen correctly.

Comment: Would I have to do this every time I switch to a new screen? This is going to be a multi level game. also that was the quickest response ever

Comment: Not versed in PyGame, tbh. Just went over documentation. I suggest creating a `screen_update` function that basically combines `screen.blit(...)` and the `pygame.display.flip()` sequentially to update your screens.